# How to create a Java mongodb driver query that is identical to this mongodb update query with arrayfilter

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

Demo https://mongoplayground.net/p/_RyWWepvpyD.

I found examples to do with spring-mongodb. But unable to find any working way to do this with mongodb driver based code.

Query:

```
 db.collection.update({
  pollID: 123
},
{
  "$inc": {
    "answerAnalytics.$[element].selectCount": 1
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "$or": [
        {
          "element.option": "1"
        },
        {
          "element.option": "2"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "multi": true
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DBCollectionFindAndModifyOptions dbCollectionFindAndModifyOptions = (new DBCollectionFindAndModifyOptions()).returnNew(true).upsert(false).update(incrObj).arrayFilters(arrayFilters);

dbCollection.findAndModify(queryDocument, dbCollectionFindAndModifyOptions);
```